Order of holding Tzitzis by Krias Shma
The Lubavitcher Rebbe writes in Hayom Yom of 22 Sivan:

לאמירת והביאנו לשלום כו' מחברים תחלה ב' הציציות דלפניו, אח"כ [אחר כך] מצרפים ציצית כנף השמאלי דלאחוריו, אח"ז [אחר זה] ציצית דכנף הימין ואוחזים אותם בין קמיצה לזרת דיד שמאל.
In Ahavat olam (p. 44-5), at the words vehavi'einu leshalom, bring together the two front tzitzit. Then join to them the tzitzit of the left back corner, then the tzitzit of the right back corner, holding them together between the little finger and ring finger of the left hand.


What is the rationale behind this order of taking hold of Tzitzis?

Is there another Minhag that says otherwise?

If one is left handed does one reverse this order or does this have nothing to do with Itur Yad?

Which hand does one hold the Tzitzis in if one is left handed?



Maybe you can find something here: http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=2538&CategoryID=787
